# Не работает preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

Нужно преобразовать ББ-теги `[hide_guest][/hide_guest]`, делаю так, но всё неизменно:

```
$parsered = 'Текст [hide_guest]Скрыто[/hide_guest] Текст';

$text = preg_replace_callback('#\[hide_guest\](.+?)\[/hide_guest\]#si', 'hide_guest', $parsered);

function hide_guest($match)
{
return '<div class="spoiler">'.$match[1].'</div>';
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: а что на выводе хотите получить? ваш код мне выдает `Текст <div class="spoiler">Скрыто</div> Текст`

Comment: @strangeqargo, смешно, но внёс правки в вопрос и код заработал )

Comment: Тогда удаляйте вопрос.

Comment: @Rammsteinik, в вашем примере функция `preg_replace_callback` не нужна, хватит просто `preg_replace`.

Comment: более того хватит и str_replace

Comment: @Naumov, если я напишу bb-код заглавными, то нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем str_replace вам не подходит? Отработает намного быстрее.
Вот так должно работать корректно:

```
$text = str_replace('[hide_guest]', '<div class="spoiler">', $parsered);

$text = str_replace('[/hide_guest]', '</div>', $text);
```

И это работает быстрее чем регулярные выражения

Comment: Если я напишу bb-код заглавными буквами, то ваша замена перестанет работать.

Comment: @Visman дело в том что bb код часто вставляеться js, и человек пишет по анологии вставки, или же есть справка краткая мол `[hide_guest]` к примеру. А люди которые будут писать большими буквами спецом, то они увидят что код не сработал и отредактируют сообщение.